# In Google Analytics I have some "properties & apps" that are no longer used. How can I delete them?

Tags: google-analytics

From my Analytics page, there is the pull-down titled "All Web Site Data" where it lists each of the apps/properties I have set up. Some of these are out-dated and no longer used. I don't see anywhere how I can delete those. Also, I'd like to change the name of one of them. I assume that as long as I don't change the UA-XXXX-XX code then I should be allowed to do that, no?

**How can I rename or delete my individual "properties & apps"?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you are logged into Google Analytics:

1. Go to "Admin" (the gear at the lower left).
2. Under "Property" (the center column), click the drop down and select from the list which property you would like to remove or rename.
3. Click "Property Settings" in the big list underneath the property name.
4. Rename the property or click "Move to Trash Can"

Comment: Do the same as above for Views that you want to delete or rename, but via the relevant View Settings page